# operator new inside namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, new-operator, compiler-bug

```
namespace X
{
  void* operator new (size_t);
}
```

gives error message as:

```
error: ‘void* X::operator new(size_t)’ may not be declared within a namespace
```

Is it a [gcc compiler bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2008-02/msg00712.html) ? In older gcc version it seems to be working.
Any idea, why it's not allowed ?

**Use case**:
I wanted to allow only custom `operator new/delete` for the classes and wanted to disallow global `new/operator`. Instead of linker error, it was easy to catch compiler error; so I coded:

```
namespace X {
  void* operator new (size_t);
}
using namespace X;
```

This worked for older version of gcc but not for the new one.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568168/testoperator-new ?

Comment: If you want to use a custom operator for the classes give them a common base class with that custom operator.

Comment: @sharptooth that is useless if those classes reside in a different third party library!!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Sharptooth's Answer makes more sense if we consider this section from the standard:

***3.7.3.1 Allocation functions [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]***

> [..] An allocation function shall be a class member function or a global function; a program is ill-formed if an allocation function is declared in a namespace scope other than global scope or declared static in global scope. [..]

The above limitation is probably imposed for the very reason that @sharptooth's answer points out.

Answer (score 14):

This is not allowed because it makes no sense. For example you have the following

```
int* ptr = 0;

namespace X {
    void* operator new (size_t);
    void operator delete(void*);
    void f()
    {
       ptr = new int();
    }
}

void f()
{
    delete ptr;
    ptr = 0;
}
```

now how should the `ptr` be `delete`d - with global namespace `operator delete()` or with the one specific to `namespace X`? There's no possible way for C++ to deduce that.

Comment: I have posted one use case. There can be other use case also where one may want to use it the operator only within `namespace` scope.

Comment: See the discussion on the [g++ bug report you referenced](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13903).  This is forbidden by the standard.

Comment: +1, agree with @sharptooth (I had thought of this problem earlier; but I was using this overload for some other purpose)

Comment: There is a possible way, C++ should first look for the namespace where `*ptr` belongs to. This is the global namespace, because the type of `ptr` is `int*`. Thus, `delete` should use the global operator. But, in for any class in `namespace X { ... }`, it should first check for `X::operator new`, and use the global `::operator new` if it does not exist. It is so trivial, so obivous! Absolutely not surprising that it does not exist in C++.