# Have different new operators in one C++ program: How to? Bad idea?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, new-operator

I have different memory allocators in my code: One for CUDA (managed or not), one for pure host memory. I could also imagine a situation when you want to use different allocation algorithms - one for large, long living blocks for example and another one for short living, small objects.

I wonder how to implement such a system properly.

**Placement new?**

My current solution uses placement new, where the pointer decides which memory and memory allocator to use. Care must then be taken when deleting/de-allocating the objects. Currently, it works, but I think it's not a nice solution.

```
MyObj* cudaObj = new(allocateCudaMemoryField(sizeof(MyObj)) MyObj(arg1, arg2);
MyObj* hostObj = new(allocateHostMemoryField(sizeof(MyObj)) MyObj(arg1, arg2);
```

**Overload new, but how?**

I'd like to go for a solution with an overloaded `new` operator. Something that will look as follows:

```
MyObj* cudaObj = CudaAllocator::new MyObj(arg1, arg2);
MyObj* hostObj = HostAllocator::new MyObj(arg1, arg2);
CudaAllocator::delete cudaObj;
HostAllocator::delete hostObj;
```

I think I could achieve this by having a namespace `CudaAllocator` and `HostAllocator`, each with an overloaded `new` and `delete`.

Two questions:

- Is it reasonable to have different overloads of `new` in a code or is
  this a sign for a design flaw?
- If it's ok, how to implement it best?

Comment: Think first about the objects you don't directly allocate yourself, such as those inside containers such as std::vector.  Typically, when overloading new, you want to associate the overload with the type being allocated, as you will find in many online examples, so a MyObj allocated inside a container gets the same allocator as one you allocate yourself.  Your idea **may** be a better fit for **your** goals.  You gave an example of the same type allocated with different allocators.  I'm just saying you should think through the harder cases before deciding.

Comment: CUDA custom memory allocators  are pretty much a solved problem in the CUDA thrust library (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9007343/681865) for example). It might be just as easy to use the existing thrust infrastructure as to (re)invent your own.

Comment: The idea with an inherited custom allocator seems good, but I think the thrust library itself does not help here. I have to make objects available on the GPU and I do not see how thrust would help me to do so in a way which is not already covered by CUDA's managed memory.

Comment: You should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210921/operator-new-inside-namespace. An allocation function must be in the global or class scope.

Answer (score 3):

There is a time and place for overloading operator `new`/`delete`, but it is generally preferred only when simpler measures have been exhausted.

The main disadvantage of placement `new` is that it requires the caller to "remember" how the object was allocated and take the appropriate action to invoke the corresponding de-allocation when that object has reached the end of its lifespan. Additionally, requiring the caller to invoke placement `new` is syntactically burdensome (I presume this is the "not a nice solution" you mention.)

The main disadvantage to overloading `new`/`delete` is that it is meant to be done once for a given type (as @JSF pointed out). This tightly couples an object to the way it is allocated/deallocated.

### Overloaded new/delete

Presuming this set up:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void* allocateCudaMemoryField(size_t size)
{
   std::cout << "allocateCudaMemoryField" << std::endl;
   return new char[size]; // simulated
}
void* allocateHostMemoryField(size_t size)
{
   std::cout << "allocateHostMemoryField" << std::endl;
   return new char[size];
}
void deallocateCudaMemoryField(void* ptr, size_t)
{
   std::cout << "deallocateCudaMemoryField" << std::endl;
   delete ptr; // simulated
}
void deallocateHostMemoryField(void* ptr, size_t)
{
   std::cout << "deallocateHostMemoryField" << std::endl;
   delete ptr;
}
```

Here's `MyObj` with overloaded `new`/`delete` (your question):

```
struct MyObj
{
   MyObj(int arg1, int arg2)
   {
      cout << "MyObj()" << endl;
   }
   ~MyObj()
   {
      cout << "~MyObj()" << endl;
   }
   static void* operator new(size_t)
   {
      cout << "MyObj::new" << endl;
      return ::operator new(sizeof(MyObj));
   }
   static void operator delete(void* ptr)
   {
      cout << "MyObj::delete" << endl;
      ::operator delete(ptr);
   }
};

MyObj* const ptr = new MyObj(1, 2);
delete ptr;
```

Prints the following:

> MyObj::new
>  MyObj()
>  ~MyObj()
>  MyObj::delete

### C Plus Plusy Solution

A better solution might be to use RAII pointer types combined with a factory to hide the details of allocation and deallocation from the caller. This solution uses placement `new`, but handles deallocation by attaching a deleter callback method to a `unique_ptr`.

```
class MyObjFactory
{
public:
   static auto MakeCudaObj(int arg1, int arg2)
   {
      constexpr const size_t size = sizeof(MyObj);
      MyObj* const ptr = new (allocateCudaMemoryField(size)) MyObj(arg1, arg2);
      return std::unique_ptr <MyObj, decltype(&deallocateCudaObj)> (ptr, deallocateCudaObj);
   }
   static auto MakeHostObj(int arg1, int arg2)
   {
      constexpr const size_t size = sizeof(MyObj);
      MyObj* const ptr = new (allocateHostMemoryField(size)) MyObj(arg1, arg2);
      return std::unique_ptr <MyObj, decltype(&deallocateHostObj)> (ptr, deallocateHostObj);
   }

private:
   static void deallocateCudaObj(MyObj* ptr) noexcept
   {
      ptr->~MyObj();
      deallocateCudaMemoryField(ptr, sizeof(MyObj));
   }
   static void deallocateHostObj(MyObj* ptr) noexcept
   {
      ptr->~MyObj();
      deallocateHostMemoryField(ptr, sizeof(MyObj));
   }
};

{
  auto objCuda = MyObjFactory::MakeCudaObj(1, 2);
  auto objHost = MyObjFactory::MakeHostObj(1, 2);
}
```

Prints:

> allocateCudaMemoryField
>   MyObj()
>   allocateHostMemoryField
>   MyObj()
>   ~MyObj()
>   deallocateHostMemoryField
>   ~MyObj()
>   deallocateCudaMemoryField

### Generic Version

This gets better. With this same strategy, we can handle the allocation/deallocation semantics for any class.

```
class Factory
{
public:
   // Generic versions that don't care what kind object is being allocated
   template <class T, class... Args>
   static auto MakeCuda(Args... args)
   {
      constexpr const size_t size = sizeof(T);
      T* const ptr = new (allocateCudaMemoryField(size)) T(args...);
      using Deleter = void(*)(T*);
      using Ptr = std::unique_ptr <T, Deleter>;
      return Ptr(ptr, deallocateCuda <T>);
   }
   template <class T, class... Args>
   static auto MakeHost(Args... args)
   {
      constexpr const size_t size = sizeof(T);
      T* const ptr = new (allocateHostMemoryField(size)) T(args...);
      using Deleter = void(*)(T*);
      using Ptr = std::unique_ptr <T, Deleter>;
      return Ptr(ptr, deallocateHost <T>);
   }

private:
   template <class T>
   static void deallocateCuda(T* ptr) noexcept
   {
      ptr->~T();
      deallocateCudaMemoryField(ptr, sizeof(T));
   }
   template <class T>
   static void deallocateHost(T* ptr) noexcept
   {
      ptr->~T();
      deallocateHostMemoryField(ptr, sizeof(T));
   }
};
```

Used with a new class S:

```
struct S
{
   S(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z)
   {
      cout << "S()" << endl;
   }
   ~S()
   {
      cout << "~S()" << endl;
   }
   int x, y, z;
};
{
   auto objCuda = Factory::MakeCuda <S>(1, 2, 3);
   auto objHost = Factory::MakeHost <S>(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Prints:

> allocateCudaMemoryField
>       S()
>       allocateHostMemoryField
>       S()
>       ~S()
>       deallocateHostMemoryField
>       ~S()
>       deallocateCudaMemoryField

I didn't want to crank the templating full blast, but obviously that code is ripe for DRYing out (parameterize the implementations on allocator function).

### Considerations

This works out pretty well when your objects are relatively large and not allocated/deallocated too frequently. I wouldn't use this if you have millions of objects coming and going every second.

Some of the same strategies work, but you want to also consider tactics like

- bulk allocation/deallocation at the beginning/end of a processing stage
- object pools that maintain a free list
- C++ allocator objects for containers like `vector`
- etc.

It really depends on your needs.

### tl;dr

No. Don't overload `new`/`delete` in this situation. Build an allocator that delegates to your generic memory allocators.

Comment: If you want to use this object in a STL container, you're out of luck with this solution (unless you make a container of pointers and perform the memory allocation/deallocation yourself)